# Android-unable to measure constraintLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to get the measuredWidth and measuredHeight  of a customview i  have created. but everytime i call one of the variants to measure i still get back 0 values.

lets have a look at the xml file so you can see what the  custom view looks like:

**retry_img.xml:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_retry"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_retry_btn"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<org.someOtherCustomView.Not.Important
    android:id="@+id/loading_shimmer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout="@layout/img_loading_layout" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

now i also have a custom view class i have created which utilizes this layout, that looks like this:

```
class MyCustomImageView : ConstraintLayout {

constructor(p0: Context) : super(p0)
constructor(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?) : super(p0, p1)
constructor(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?, p2: Int) : super(p0, p1, p2)


init {
    inflate(context, R.layout.retry_img, this)
    measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
   Log.d(TAG,"$measuredWidth") //this is always zero, why ? 
}
```

}

i tried `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY and MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`  same results.

lets  take a look at how i actually use it which might help :

it  is inside  another constraintLayout which looks like this:

**my_main_layout.xml:**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="256dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="11dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

 <org.somecompany.MyCustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,232:60"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_placeholder" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

notice i use a **app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio**  thats why i set 0's on the width  and heights. I also  tried this customview(MyCustomImageView) in another layout file but same results. any ideas.

Comment: Your custom view is created and the init block runs before layout completes. At this point, nothing really has a size. You will need to delay grabbing the width until after layout completes. You attempt to get the width with `measure()` is also specifying an exact measure of _0_ so, even if layout is complete, you would still get zero. (Search for "how android draws views" for information on these things.)  Since there are several ways to get the width, if you can specify when you need to get the width, you will probably get a usable answer.

Comment: As soon as view gets inflated i need to know it's dimensions so i can make a network call to fetch an image. The network call require width and height of the view

Comment: onPredraw is a little  slow for me  to wait on ..is wish i can meaasure it myself.

Comment: Try overriding [_onSizeChanged()_](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to capture the width. You could also capture the width before layout if you can make some assumptions about the view's parent. You would need to build a proper [_MeasureSpec_](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html#makeMeasureSpec(int,%20int)) that incorporates the width.

Comment: this works great ..i put a rx subject in there to fire and if it executed i start my load. thanks if you need to make answer you can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for anyone who needs a little help i used an rxSubject like this:

```
1. create a behaviorSubject so you always know when size changes. 

private var subject = BehaviorSubject.create<Any>()

2. then override it:

     override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
             subject.onNext(Any())
        }

3. use it as a trigger:

 subject.switchMap { //got the size do something }.subscribe(//...)
```

i suppose latestFrom operator could have also been used as a trigger but simplest was behaviorsubject to me to remember the last emission (free cache).

Comment: this answer really helped me as i was using an old version of glide and it has bugs that i had to know when the view was actually measured.